# Rollback python 2.7.13 to 2.7.11

Tags: python, windows

For some backwards compatability test I want to be able to rollback python 2.7.13 to 2.7.11.

I could do a VM and what not but really its more work then its worth as this is definately a one off scenario and or may prove to be a red herring.

I cant seem to roll the version of python it seems to be remebering the version.

```
>>python --version 
Python 2.7.13

*Uninstall python using the 2.7.13 installer. 

>>python --version
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

*Install python using the 2.7.11 installer. 

>>python --version 
Python 2.7.13
```

Some how python is remebering its version after a 'complete' removal and reinstall. It must be hinding something somewhere ... can anyone tell me how to effectively rollback the python version?

Comment: If you want to test backwards compatability use something like Anaconda

Comment: @chrisz I'm testing something different here -- Anaconda would inject new variables into the environment that would not exist in production.  I need the base distro as that is what will be used.

Comment: What do you mean "inject new variables into the environment"?

Comment: @chriz Anaconda bundles quite a bit that would not be there in practice with our product. So using anaconda could suppress errors that would show up on a production set up.  Its especially important since system dependencies are my main concern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). It basically allows you manage different versions of Python. It has the same idea as nvm for NodeJS.

Comment: Any idea if pyenv plays nice with virtualenvs?

Comment: I did not have problems with making them work together. Let us know if you do.